# No PID file created when starting Puma as daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I am working on getting my Rails app deployed using Nginx as a reverse proxy. Everything work correctly when starting the app manually using `rails s` to launch it. All the proper PIDs are created in the `tmp/pids/` directory (`puma.pid, puma.state, andserver.pid`) and the `puma.sock` is properly created in the `tmp/sockets/` directory.

When I attempt to start the same app using `rails s -d`, to start it as a daemon, everything start normally except the `tmp/pids/puma.pid` is nowhere to be found which causes my reverse proxy to break. I'll paste a copy of my `puma.conf` below.

Using:
`puma 3.12.6` and `rails 5.2.6`

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 4 }

preload_app!

plugin :tmp_restart

# Prep for Nginx integration
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
tmp_dir = "#{app_dir}/tmp"

bind "unix://#{tmp_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
pidfile "#{tmp_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{tmp_dir}/pids/puma.state"

activate_control_app
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem occurs when launching the Rails server and using the `-d` switch to daemonize (which I was doing) like this:

`rails s -d`

However, if I add `daemonize true` to the `puma.conf` everything works as expected. So, now I launch the server using `rails s` with the following `puma.conf` and the missing `puma.pid` appears!

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked webserver processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 4 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart

# Prep for Nginx integration
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
tmp_dir = "#{app_dir}/tmp"

bind "unix://#{tmp_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
pidfile "#{tmp_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{tmp_dir}/pids/puma.state"

# Run Puma as a daemon
daemonize true

activate_control_app
```

Answer (score 1):

to `config/puma.rb`
add `pidfile "tmp/pids/server.pid"`